# Google map touch controls in Android App

Tags: android, google-maps

Is it possible to use the controls that exists in the default maps app in a MapView? I specifically want to integrate the touch controls that allow the user to rotate the map with two fingers and tilting the angle of the map by touching the sides.
I am curious because zoom and move controls exist without any indication in the java code.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Once you've received a key to Google API; you should be able to use the SDK to access the default controls.  The one I believe you want is: [`setBuiltInZoomControls` which basically enables the default use controls](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/MapView.html#setBuiltInZoomControls%28boolean%29%5bLink%5d).

Comment: hmmm I've tried this and it sets the zoom buttons on the bottom of the map that look like: (+ / -). After doing some more reading, I think the controls I want, rotating and tilting, do not have default support.  Thank you though.

Comment: Are you referencing the multi-touch gesture support that Samsung Integrated to certain applications while using TouchWiz?  If you hold a finger in left or right corner then move the tablet it "zooms" for example?

Comment: I believe not?
I realize this link describes the controls that I want to use.  http://support.google.com/mobile/bin/static.py?hl=en&page=guaside.cs&guide=1088497

Comment: Site isn't loading, the controls it sounded like to me are:                   http://www.androidpit.com/en/android/blog/399185/The-Samsung-Galaxy-Note-With-Gesture-Controls-Hands-On-Review-And-Video" Samsung Gesture "Tipping"  If this is the gesture your referencing it isn't a default-support.

Comment: hmm yeah I guess it isn't supported.  Thanks though! Really appreciate it!

Comment: No problem, sorry I couldn't be more help.